# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages _Layout.cshtml.css not applied

Tags: asp.net-core, layout, razor-pages, sticky-footer

I stumbled around a Problem with the CSS file `_Layout.cshtml.css`. Well, the short and quick description, the CSS class 'footer' is not applied. Other CSS classes like 'border-top' and 'text-center' do work just fine. But `footer` class is just not applied or broken. Also, I tried to use `@RenderSection("footer", required: false)` but that also just did nothing. For testing purpose, I renamed the CSS class to something like `my-test` and only set `text-align: center;` but the text is not centered.

The last two days, I googled about how to make the footer sticky on the bottom, since it is always on top. Doesn't matter what I tried, the CSS class `footer` never got applied. Also, other changes to `_Layout.cshtml.css` are not reflected. I can make a sticky footer on the bottom of the site, with centered text, by mixing class and style tags within the `_Layout.cshtml` file. But that bugs me out. Why can't I use the `_Layout.cshtml.css` file and the CSS class `footer` to adjust the layout?
What do I miss here?

[image: _Layout.cshtml.css]

The Result should look something like this:
[image: Sticky footer]
But without the need to mix .css and HTML style tag.

I tried the following edits:

Added @RenderSection("footer", required: false)
[image: RenderSection]
[image]

Defining the 'footer' class in the footer:
[image: Footer class in footer element]
[image]

Defining the 'footer' class in a div element:
[image: Footer class in div element]

Defining a CSS class for centering the text:
[image: Center text class in _Layout.cshtml.css]
[image]

Added `@await RenderSection("footer", required: false)` and used 'my-test' as CSS class to center the text on a div element:
[image: RenderSection() and custom CSS class in _Layout.cshtml.css]

Comment: It would be great if you could share your code snippet instead of screenshot. 
Post the code and error as text, not images. Images can't be copied, googled or tested.

Comment: There is no error message. It's just not applied. Even changes to the .css and rebuilding the application does not apply to that .css. And about the code snippet, there is the whole footer as .css within the image, for what you need a snippet?

Answer (score 1):

1. In `_Layout.cshtml` make sure your link tag has a correct name in href (I encountered this myself after renaming my project name. rename **YourProjectNameHere** with your project name!):

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/YourProjectNameHere.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
   ```
2. If it still didn't applied yet, after the 1st step try to clean and rebuild solution and then check it again. with this step compiler's generated strings for styles and HTML tags (that you can see in the inspector) will probably going to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like below ?

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

html:

```
 <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2023 - areacore - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Exactly like this, but it does not work. I've started to put my css code into the site.css. But I am not so sure if this is the right place for such changes in ASP.NET. Looks like a bug in the css Isolation system to me. I've found a similar post on the forum here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71608095/razor-pages-css-isolation-styles-for-some-html-tags-are-not-working), but unfortunately, what did work for this user, do not work for me. When I put the css class into the site.css, it will be applied. Just that scoped .css do not work.